# I am sending broadcast from appA to appB. To upgrade my code to Android O I have converted my implicit Broadcast to explicit, but it's not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

Manifest.xml of receiving app.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<receiver android:name=".DemoReceiver"
        android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myparentapplication.demo"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver declared in receiving app:

```
public class DemoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public DemoReceiver(){}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Received");

    String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    Toast.makeText(context,"opening the intent data : " + data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
  }
}
```

Broadcast sent by broadcasting app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.myparentapplication.demo");
            intent.putExtra("data","job dispatched");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), "com.example.myparentapplication.DemoReceiver"));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This way I am using broadcast after upgrading my api to Android 'O', but I am not receiving any broadcast. where as in documentation it says that explicit broadcast are allow to register in manifest after Android Oreo. Please guide me appropriately that what is wrong here? 
**Note:**  Receiving app is a background app. so I can not register broadcast dynamically. I have tried almost all the solution from stack overflow but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), "com.example.myparentapplication.DemoReceiver"));
```

`getApplicationContext().getPackageName()` will return the application ID of the *sending* app. Your `ComponentName` needs the application ID of the *receiving* app.